# MySQL: Strange behavior after importing DB and FLUSH PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql, debian

I've imported my old database (via phpMyAdmin) and everything seemed to be fine - except for the user/password combinations. I tried to do a "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" and afterwards, I couldn't login anymore into my root account either (which was working).

I tried to reset it via stopping the mysqld, starting mysqld_safe with the --skip-grant-tables flag and reset the root password. It returned no error message, but when I tried to login I still got 'Access denied'.

Any idea of what might have gone wrong?

Thanks a lot!

PS: This is on a Debian 5.0.6 System

---

EDIT:
Somehow my root account was gone. I had to repeat the steps again, reset all the other passwords in the mysql.user table and add a new root account via

```
mysql> INSERT INTO user VALUES ('localhost','root',password('newpass'),'Y','Y ','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y', 'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','' ,'','','',0,0,0,0);
mysql> INSERT INTO user VALUES ('127.0.0.1','root',password('newpass'),'Y','Y ','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y', 'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','' ,'','','',0,0,0,0);
```

Now it's working again.

Thanks for all the replies!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just stop mysql [use kill if needed] and run it for a second with [--skip-grant-tables](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442) option, change password for both root and debian-sys-maint password [so it matches one in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf ]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it does anything other than run `mysqld_safe etc` but I ran

```
dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.0
```

and it gave me the option to reset the root password.